# New Line in File Writer From Existing Multi-Lined String

Tags: java, newline

I am trying to output a multi-line string to a file using FileWriter. How can I make it recognize the lines and automatically use "output.newLine"?

Example String

```
static String test = "This \n" + "is \n" + "a \n" + "sample \n" + "string."


public static void testMethod (String test){
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter ("output.txt", true)
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter);

bufferedWriter.write (test);
bufferedWriter.close ();
}
```

Comment: This is in java. But im sure it's very similar to c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text.split("\n")` to create multiple lines and write them separately.

Comment: Like this? :
    public static void main test (String test){
    test.split ("\n);
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter ("output.txt", true)
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter);

    bufferedWriter.write (test);
    bufferedWriter.close ();
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `\n` with the platform new line with.

```
bufferedWriter.write(test.replaceAll("\n", System,getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: i fixed it to (test.replaceAll ("\n", System.getProperty ("line.seperator"))); and it's still not working

Comment: Im sorry i wasn't very descriptive.

Here is the error:
    `code` at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source) 

    `code` at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)

I imported java.lang.String, that should be enough, i believe.